# Как сделать чтобы при выделенной ссылке отображался конкретный слайдер

Tags: javascript

Как сделать , что-то в таком духе , может есть какие решение готовые?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я немного не понял структуру, ссылка должна быть в слайдере или при выделеной ссылке отображался конкретный слайдер?

Comment: при выделенной ссылке отображался конкретный слайдер, хотелось бы без костылей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var slider1 = document.getElementsByClassName('slider1')[0];
var slider2 = document.getElementsByClassName('slider2')[0];
var slider3 = document.getElementsByClassName('slider3')[0];

function slider(count) {
  if (count == 1) {
    slider1.style.display = "block";
    slider2.style.display = "none";
    slider3.style.display = "none";
  } else if (count == 2) {
    slider1.style.display = "none";
    slider2.style.display = "block";
    slider3.style.display = "none";
  } else if (count == 3) {
    slider1.style.display = "none";
    slider2.style.display = "none";
    slider3.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}
ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
}
ul li a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  transition: .2s;
}
ul li a:hover {
  background: #aaa;
}
.carusel {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul class="links">
  <li><a href="#" onclick="slider(1);">link1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="slider(2);">link2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="slider(3);">link3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="slider1 carusel">Slider1</div>
<div class="slider2 carusel">Slider2</div>
<div class="slider3 carusel">Slider3</div>
```

Comment: а на jquery примерно как будет ?

Comment: $('.slider1').css('display', 'none');

Comment: или что именно на jquery?

Comment: то как вы реализовали на js сейчас слайдер , на jquery будет таким же громоздким ?

Comment: да, ещё компактнее сделать будет сложно

Comment: он и так не очень большой, все же если подходит не забудьте про галочку

Answer (score 2):

Зачем городить кучу кода, если есть циклы.

```js
const carusel = document.getElementsByClassName('carusel');
const a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  a[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      carusel[i].style.opacity = '0';
    }
    carusel[i].style.opacity = '1';
  })
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  transition: background .2s;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background: #aaa;
}

.caruselWrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.carusel {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}
```

```html
<ul class="links">
  <li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="caruselWrap">
  <div class="carusel">Slider1</div>
  <div class="carusel">Slider2</div>
  <div class="carusel">Slider3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: А мне твой ответ больше понравился